# map comparator for sorting map elements

Tags: c++

I wanted the elements of the map to be arranged in a specific sequence(shortest first).
So i wrote a simple comparator which compares the length of the elements being inserted in the map with the previous element(s).

```
struct cmpByStringLength {
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
        return a.length() < b.length();
    }
};

int main()
{
        map<string,string,cmpByStringLength> obj1;
        obj1.insert(make_pair("Anurag","Last"));
        obj1.insert(make_pair("Second","Last"));

        for(map<string,string>::iterator it=obj1.begin();it!= obj1.end();++it)
        {
                cout<<it->first;
                cout<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

But the above won't insert element with key as `Second` in the map since the comparator compares elements with keys `Second` with `Anurag` and they have equal length so doesn't insert element with key `Second`. However the following would work fine:

```
    obj1.insert(make_pair("abc","Last"));
    obj1.insert(make_pair("abcdefg","Last"));
    obj1.insert(make_pair("abcd","Last"));
```

Turns out, my understanding about custom comparator to sort the elements in a map is wrong as it is used for inserting the elements and not for inserting it as per the sort logic i provided through comparator.

So in other words, is it correct to say that custom comparators are just used for deciding *whether or not* to insert an element at all in the map, and it is not used to decide *where* to place the element?

Comment: Because length is not a hash.. they are both the same length so of course it's not going to insert another item in the map with the same length which is being used as a hash

Comment: @Brandon: `std::map` doesn't use hashes (perhaps you're thinking of `std::unordered_map`?)... The problem is similar (the length is effectively the only thing that matters for equality based on this comparator), but it's unrelated to hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ documentation on `map` (and really anything using a `std::less`-style comparator) makes it quite clear that two elements `a`, `b` are equivalent iff `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` (see, for example, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). This means that, yes, your comparator gets used for ordering *and* equivalence testing.

The way you'd usually fix this is to implement a two-level comparison, e.g.

```
return (a.length() == b.length()) ? (a < b) : (a.length() < b.length());
```

Comment: The actual issue i am facing is that e.g. in anycase where i want to return false so that the existing element can be inserted after the element being compared, it doesn’t get inserted at all. In short everytime a false is returned, the element won’t be inserted, however my logic or inserting before the exisitng element is based upon true or false. True being insert before and false means insert after. Can’t this be achieved?

Comment: Not with `map` - maps *must* be strongly ordered so that insertion order cannot matter. Could you just do a `std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<string, string>>>` instead, keyed first on the length? That looks hairier but it would satisfy your needs I think?

Comment: Note: Because multi-level comparisons get tricky, it might be worth delegating the comparison to `std::tuple`, e.g. `return std::make_tuple(a.length(), std::cref(a)) < std::make_tuple(b.length(), std::cref(b));` or something to that effect (the `std::cref` being there to avoid copying `a`/`b`, with `std::tie` not being an option since `.length()` returns an r-value). Avoids complexity of hand-writing fallback comparisons, especially if you need more than one fallback comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::multimap` can solve your problem. But I don't know size of your data so I can't comment how it will effect performance on your application.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct cmpByStringLength {
  bool operator()(const std::string &a, const std::string &b) const {
    return a.length() < b.length();
  }
};

int main() {
  multimap<string, string, cmpByStringLength> obj1;
  obj1.insert(make_pair("Second1", "Last"));
  obj1.insert(make_pair("Anurag", "Last"));
  obj1.insert(make_pair("Second", "Last"));
  obj1.insert(make_pair("Secon", "Last"));

  for (map<string, string>::iterator it = obj1.begin(); it != obj1.end();
       ++it) {
    cout << it->first;
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> Secon
>
> Anurag
>
> Second
>
> Second1